# Creating a Rechart bar chart with a triangular end

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using rechart to generate a waterfall bar chart. Below is how the chart looks like where I am able to get a rounded edge for the bar using the radius tag

[image: Waterfall bar chart]

Is there any way to get a triangular end to one side of the bar where the edges are rounded similar to the image below.

[image: Traingular bar end]

Here is the code I have to display the bar chart

```
<BarChart
                  width={1000}
                  height={400}
                  data={data}
                  margin={{
                    top: 20,
                    right: 30,
                    left: 150,
                    bottom: 5,
                  }}
                  layout="vertical"
                >
                  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                  <XAxis type="number" ticks={tickValue} />
                  <YAxis dataKey="name" type="category" />
                  <Tooltip />
                  <Bar dataKey="end" stackId="a" fill="transparent" />
                  <Bar
                    dataKey="start"
                    stackId="a"
                    fill="#82ca9d"
                    radius={[10, 0, 0, 10]}
                    label={{ dataKey: 'barValue', position: 'center', fill: 'black' }}
                  >
                    {data.map((item, index) => {
                      if (item.start < 0) {
                        return <Cell key={index} stroke="#115c11" fill="#228B22" />;
                      }
                      return <Cell key={index} stroke="#941d10" fill="#d93321" />;
                    })}
                  </Bar>
                </BarChart>
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

I want a triangular end to one end of the bar but could only achieve a rounded edge by using the radius tag.